# Error in Ruby/RSpec/WebDriver > expected respond to 'has_content?'

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

Can anyone explain this error?

My `spec_helper.rb` requires `capybara`, `rspec`, and `selenium-webdriver`.

My `test_spec.rb` file contains the following:

```
require_relative 'spec_helper'

@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
@browser.get "http://www.google.com"

describe 'ErrorCheck' do
  it 'should log in to Trialnet' do
    expect(@browser).to have_content('Search')
  end
end
```

My error:

```
expected  to respond to `has_content?`
./spec/webdriver3_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why this expectation is failing? Is it returning a Boolean without the proper syntax to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `@browser` instance variable is not available to the `it` statement.  Notice that your error message doesn't have a reference to the object that it is performing an expectation on (i.e.  `expected  to respond to 'has_content?'`.

Here's a contrived demonstration that shows it fail:

```
require 'rspec'

@x = 1

describe 'One' do
  it 'should print 1' do
    expect(@x).to eq 1
  end
end

Failures:

  1) One should print 1
     Failure/Error: expect(@x).to eq 1

       expected: 1
            got: nil
```

And--by moving the instance variable into the `it` statement to available--the example passes:

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'One' do
  it 'should print 1' do
    @x = 1
    expect(@x).to eq 1
  end
end

1 example, 0 failures
```

And--if you use [`let`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/MemoizedHelpers/ClassMethods#let-instance_method)--you can created a memoized variable that can be shared across examples:

```
require 'rspec'

describe 'One' do

  let(:x) { 1 }

  it 'should print 1' do
    expect(x).to eq 1
  end

  it 'should print 2' do
    expect(x+1).to eq 2
  end  

end
```

Based on your example code, you could use a `before` block for setup and then use [`subject`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/MemoizedHelpers#subject-instance_method), which is probably more appropriate than `let` (NOTE: snippet below is untested, and the difference between `let` and `subject` is covered in other SO answers, various blog posts, and rdoc):

```
describe 'ErrorCheck' do

  before :all do
    @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @browser.get "http://www.google.com"
  end

  subject(:browser) {@browser}       # or let(:browser) {@browser}

  it 'should log in to Trialnet' do
    expect(@browser).to have_content('Search')
  end
end
```

Comment: I see the concept here. In your example, it makes sense because you're passing a finite integer into a variable then performing an expectation on that variable. However, I'm a little confused how I can pass the entire contents of a page (the one I'm checking for the word 'Search') into a variable, which I would then theoretically check for that string.

Comment: You can pass any object to `let`, it doesn't have to be a literal.